# Passing data between Vue siblings

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

> After researching this question thoroughly and after implementing the Bus method to communicate between siblings, I am getting a webpack error, so either i'm
>   not implementing right (using latest CLI as of yesterday), or I need some other method.

I am new to Vue, coming from React and I have built a simple app wrapping 2 components in `app.vue`:

an input that sends data:

```
<GoogleInput @searchEvent="getSearchLocation($event)"></GoogleInput>
```

and a map container that should receive the data:

```
<GoogleMapsContainer :location="location" name="location-project"></GoogleMapsContainer>
```

I successfully implemented child (`GoogleInput`) to parent communication in `app.js` via:

```
getSearchLocation(input) {
  this.location = input;
}
```

with a method in `GoogleInput`:

`this.$emit('searchEvent', ev.target.value);`

Up to here everything was smooth.

---

Yet when trying to communicate my input value through to sibling (`GoogleMapsContainer`) via the bus method:

In my entry index.js:  `const Bus = new Vue({});`

A new emit in my sending component:

`Bus.$emit('passLocation', {location: this.location})`

and in my receiving component:

`Bus.$on('passLocation', (input) => {
     this.location = input;
 });`

I get a webpack error:

`Error in created hook: "TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_vue__.$on is not a function"`

I am looking for "the shortest distance" to communicate my input to map container, without going into solving webpack issues (if this is a webpack issue at all, or just a fat finger mistake).

> BTW: If vuex isn't a time consuming method to implement (as React-Redux is) in here, that
>   would be a cool route as well, but I must keep this design (already in
>   Git)

Thanks

Comment: When you made the Bus component, did you include it in component that it's being executed in?

Comment: Yes, included in both components.

Comment: I'm new to vue myself but I think you are calling it before the lifecycle of the second component starts. Try wrapping it in the lifecycle hook for mounted, so you'd have `mounted () {Bus.$on('passLocation', (input) => {
     this.location = input;
 });}`

Comment: To clarify, is GoogleInput a sibling of GoogleMapsContainer? And both are inside your 'main' Vue file?

Comment: Yes, they i've invoked them under mounted ().
Can you reproduce with the CLI tje same error?

Comment: Hi Josh, everything you said is correct but only my "main" is app.vue, entry is index.js with the bus instantiated there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have some import errors.

In your index.js, export it like:

```
export const Bus = new Vue({});
```

And in the files you do `Bus.$emit(...)` or `Bus.$on(...)` import it like:

```
import { Bus } from './index'; // make sure you use the correct relative path
```